# How to access hidden instagram button using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am making a project where I want to click on the button but the button is hidden. I am working on python. [I want to access this 3 dot button which appears next to comment when i hover over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6pey.jpg)

Comment: What do you really want to do? Why do you need to click on the button? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Like Justin's answer says below, the API might be a better solution to the original problem you are trying to solve. Or there might be yet another way to get the information you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worst practice in selenium.
For multiple reasons, logging into sites like Gmail and Facebook using WebDriver is not recommended. Aside from being against the usage terms for these sites (where you risk having the account shut down), it is slow and unreliable.

The ideal practice is to use the APIs that email providers offer, or in the case of Facebook the developer tools service which exposes an API for creating test accounts, friends and so forth. Although using an API might seem like a bit of extra hard work, you will be paid back in speed, reliability, and stability. The API is also unlikely to change, whereas webpages and HTML locators change often and require you to update your test framework.

Logging in to third party sites using WebDriver at any point of your test increases the risk of your test failing because it makes your test longer. A general rule of thumb is that longer tests are more fragile and unreliable.

Please check selenium Hq web site

Comment: Oh thanks for that , but I am trying to work on instagram , is there any api for the same?

Comment: No Api , 
If my answer usefull to you pls accept my above answer by click tick